# How To Show The Code's Cell Formula, Not String?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Script, I am running the following code:

```
var test = ss.getRange("C183")  
ss.getRange("C7").setValue(test.getValue());
```

C183 =ROUND($B$27/$C$126) or [=Round(25.5/5)]

After I run the code, it gives me a string of text in C7, but I want the  actual formula. How do I get this to appear?

P.S.

Let me mention that I am running this from an onEdit function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getFormula() method can be used instead of getValue() to fetch the formula added in the cell.

```
var test = ss.getRange("C183")  
ss.getRange("C7").setValue(test.getFormula());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This has solved my problem. I do have one more question. If I have 2 cells that contain concatenations with math formulas inside of them, how then could I get the sum total of both of those cells in spite of the text inside? For example: =concatenate(Round((E48)/G127,1)," ", "of", " ", F127) + =concatenate(Round((E43)/G124,1)," ", "of", " ", F128) ?

Comment: you have to fetch the data as string only and then add them in the code to get the resultant value.